# Order elements using index number

Tags: jquery, indexing

How can I re-order elements using index number?

For example if I have a list

```
<ul>
   <li data-name="tree"></li>
   <li data-name="park"></li>
   <li data-name="house"></li>
   <li data-name="fountain"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I move 'house' to 1st place using number?
I can get the zero-based index for a list item by using `index()`, but I can't move the element to a specific index.

Example:

```
$("[data-name='house']").moveTo(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet that may help.  The offset supplied to `moveTo` is the position (0=first) to insert the element among the remaining children.  Solutions that depend on `insertBefore` or similar functions are simpler, but this version of `moveTo` should work for moving the element to any position (including before the first or after the last child) and should handle the special case where you move an only child to position zero without causing an error.

```js
$.fn.moveTo = function(i) {
    var p = this.parent()
    var c = this.detach()
    var cs = p.children()
    cs = [].concat(cs.slice(0,i), c.get(), cs.slice(i))
    p.html(cs)
}

var i = 0;
var next = function() {
  if (++i > 3) { i = 0 }
  $('[data-name="tree"]').moveTo(i)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li data-name="tree">tree</li>
   <li data-name="park">park</li>
   <li data-name="house">house</li>
   <li data-name="fountain">fountain</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="next()">Move</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.insertBefore()` and `.eq()` methods.

`eq()` method reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Please try this:

```
$('[data-name=house]').insertBefore($('li').eq(0));
```